# Polyphonic tie on lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I am writing down the lovely Old Castle from Mussorgsky. And from the beginning there is a tie linking polyphonic voices. What I want to achieve is this:

[image: tie for several voices]

but what I get is

[image: No tie]

Even if I put a tie, nothing happens. My code looks like:

```
\language "italiano"
\header {
  title = "Il Vecchio Castello from Pictures at an Exhibition"
  composer = "Modest Mussorgsky"
 }
upper = \relative do' {
  \clef treble
  \key si \major %enter preformatted text here
  \time 6/8
  R3 R3 R3
 }

lower = \relative do {
  \clef bass
  \key si \major
  \time 6/8
  <sold red'>2.~<<{red'4 red8 red^. red^. red^.} \\ {sold,4. sold} >> <<{red'8.[( mi16) red8^.] fad^.( mi^. red^.)} \\ {sold,4. sold} >>  }

 \score {
 \new PianoStaff <<
  \new Staff = "upper" \upper
   \new Staff = "lower" \lower
>>  
\layout { }
\midi {  \tempo 4 = 120 }
}
```

Any hint on how to tie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend starting the polyphonic construction immediately in the first measure. This will cause the opening G♯ to be stem down, so a quick `\once \stemUp` will move the stem up to match the notation you're looking for.

I also changed your `R3` to `R2.` to accurately reflect the meter.

```
\version "2.20.0"
\language "italiano"

upper = \relative do' {
  \clef treble
  \key si \major %enter preformatted text here
  \time 6/8
  R2. R R
 }

lower = \relative do {
  \clef bass
  \key si \major
  \time 6/8
  <<
    {
      red2.~ |
      red4 red8 red-. red-. red-. |
      red8.[( mi16) red8^.] fad^.( mi^. red^.)
    } 
    \\ 
    {
      \once \stemUp sold,2.~ |
      sold4. sold |
      sold sold |
    } 
  >>
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "upper" \upper
    \new Staff = "lower" \lower
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed @Richard, I figured out that extending the polyphonic constructions solves, but your solutions is really more elegant. Thank you! Also thank you for the R2. hint, I received lilypond warnings for this with no clue on how to solve it!

Comment: Oh and I missed the steam up, thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

### A suggestion to change your code practice:

Instead of this:

```
music = {
  ...
  <<{ ... }\\{ ... }>>
  ...
  <<{ ... }\\{ ... }>>
  ...
}
\score {
  \new Staff { \music }
}
```

Try doing this:

```
music_upper = {
  \oneVoice
  ...
  \voiceOne ... \oneVoice
  ...
  \voiceOne ... \oneVoice
  ...
}
music_lower = {
  \voiceTwo
  s
  ...
  s
  ...
  s
}
music = <<{ \music_upper }\\{ \music_lower }>>
\score {
  \new Staff { \music }
}
```

That is, instead of using `<<{}\\{}>>` multiple times within
one context, use it once, and use the combination of `\voiceOne`,
`\voiceTwo`, and `\oneVoice` to change voice directions.

### The rationale:

According to the bug thread [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-lilypond/2019-03/msg00006.html),
there’s apparently a common misconception about using the `<<{}\\{}>>` construct.
I didn’t realize it until I’d typeset several hundred short pieces, but each
time `<<{}\\{}>>` is invoked, two *additional* Voice contexts are
created. That means that if you make use of that construct several times,
you might end up with the compiled equivalent of a `\score {}` with
dozens upon dozens of `\new Voice {}` contexts.

In my case, this caused a huge slow-down, and led to compile failures. The
proposed solution was to use fewer contexts and make use of `\voiceOne`, `\voiceTwo`,
and `\oneVoice`. Using `\voice...` will automatically control certain
aspects of the notation, such as stem direction and articulation direction. (`\oneVoice` neutralizes these.)

Think of the differences this way:

```
RH = \relative c'' {
  red
  <<{ yellow }\\{ blue }>> red
  red
  <<{ green }\\{ cyan }>>
  red
}
```

[image: awful]

and this:

```
RH_upper = \relative c'' {
  red
  \voiceOne red \oneVoice red
  red
  \voiceOne red \oneVoice
  red
}
RH_lower = \relative c'' {
  s
  blue s
  s
  blue
  s
}
RH = <<{ \RH_upper }\\{ \RH_lower }>>
```

[image: better]

Five voices in five measures in the first example; two voices in the second example. It can feel a bit more cumbersome to begin with, but I think it helps in the long run, **especially** if you are going to typeset pieces longer than a few measures.

### Using this method specifically, how to make a polyphonic tie:

```
RH_upper = \relative c' {
  \oneVoice
  R2. R
}
RH_lower = \relative c' {
  s2. s
}
LH_upper = \relative c {
  \oneVoice
  <gis dis'>2.^~
  \voiceOne dis'4 dis8 dis dis dis
}
LH_lower = \relative c {
  \voiceTwo
  \once \hideNotes
  <gis dis'>2.~
  gis4. gis
}
pianoRH = <<{ \RH_upper }\\{ \RH_lower }>>
pianoLH = <<{ \LH_upper }\\{ \LH_lower }>>
```

Incidentally, you will notice that certain notation elements, such as the `.` on the first note, are correctly moved above the staff line. They will not be in the other method unless you manually correct them.

Comment: Hello Neal, indeed your suggestion looks cumbersome and I dont fully understand it. Still your suggestion is interesting as, in this piece Mussorgsky wrote for the F key almost entirely two voices and for the G key two voices in several places.So my notation and code starts to look really cumbersome as well. I am going to study your example ( switching to onevoice is what was blocking me)